# Is there any difference between calls in main thread and unsafeRunSync?

Tags: scala, cats-effect

Is there any difference between just

```
call1()
call2()
```

and

```
val res = for {
_ <- IO(call1())
_ <- IO(call2())
...
} yield somevalue

res.unsafeRunSync
```

What variant is safer (and is there any difference at all)?

Comment: `IO` is basic building block of a paradigm called [_"Programs as Values"_](https://systemfw.org/archive.html) if you are not following that paradigm then there is no reason to use `IO` at all; the second example is not following the paradigm since the point of `IO` is to compose programs together, something that is not happening there.

Comment: littlebit corrected example. So and if the case is to step-by-step refactor big application by wrapping bits of code into IO, and then finally compose them together? The question was: Is there any difference? May it be more unsafe then just sequential invocations? or it does not matter at all?

Comment: Check the blog series from Fabio I shared. As I said, _"Programs as Values"_ is a completely different paradigm with its advantages and disadvantages; You may also check this talk from Daniel for a different angle of when `IO` is useful and why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgfCmQ-2tW0&ab_channel=Konfy - Thus, if you want to move a codebase into `IO` then yeah; for whatever reasons, what you are doing is reasonable. Otherwise, there is no point, don't use a technology just for the sake of using it, but rather because you think such technology is the right choice for your problem.